# C++ program missing searched string in large .TXT files. Works for smaller .TXT files

Tags: c++, search, text, cpu-word, getline

I am writing a program to search through a very large text file with C++.

The file is a 21 million lines of code and is a backup of system file. I am trying to find the alarms that are stored inside of the code and print them out to a separate text file.

From comments below. I am unable to install any outside files or programs and it is being run on Windows Server 2012.

Currently my code works to find the first alarm string when I take a few thousand lines from the text file. But when I run the full 1GB plus text file it returns no results. It just skips over the results. I have tried allocating more memory and also an array and neither have seemed to work correctly (I could have coded it wrong I am not the best C++ coder and am learning as I go)

My question is why would it work on the smaller file, is it a memory problem? Do I need to store each line as a string as I go through then search that line, wouldn't that take much longer?

My code is as follows:

```
    // Alarms.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    system("cls");
    string PRIORITY_NAME, line;
    //bool found = false;
    ifstream myfile("fhx.txt");
    ofstream alarmList("alarmlist.txt");
    int counter = 0;

    cout << "Searching for Alarms and sending to AlarmList.txt \n";

    //make sure files are good and open and determine size
    if (myfile.is_open() && alarmList.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File is open \n";
        ifstream file("fhx.txt", ios::binary | ios::ate);
        cout << "The current open file size is " << file.tellg() << " bytes \n";
        system("pause");
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File is not open \n";
        system("pause");
    }

    cout << "Running \n"; // show program is running for user to see

    // reads the file and searches while there is still a line
    while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            ++counter;
            cout << counter << "\n"; //print out lines scanned for debug purposes

        // searches the file for PRIORITY_NAME
            if (line.find("PRIORITY_NAME") != string::npos)
            {
                alarmList << line << "\n"; // [rint results to seperate text file
                //getline(myfile, line);
                cout << line << "\n";// print to console for debug
            }
        }
    alarmList << "\n" << counter << "  lines searched\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Here is the printout when I run the smaller under 2 thousand line file

```
     PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
  PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
```

1679  lines searched

Here is a snippet of the code I am searching, it is 21 million lines like this with the first alarm not until like 17,000. Unfortunately I can not give out much more of it than this:

```
     OPERATOR_SUBSYSTEM
  {
    ENABLED=T
    GLOBAL_ALARM_ACK_GROUP=1
    RESTRICT_WRITES_TO_AREAS=T
    AREA { NAME="AREA_A" }
    AREA { NAME="K-401_SYS" }
    AREA { NAME="UTIL_AUX" }
    AREA { NAME="SIS" }
    AREA { NAME="SIS_F201_MOD" }
    AREA { NAME="SIS_COKER" }
    AREA { NAME="SIS_VRU" }
    AREA { NAME="SIS_F202_MOD" }
    AREA { NAME="SIS_F203_MOD" }
    AREA { NAME="SISCD201_2_SEQ" }
    AREA { NAME="SISCD203_4_SEQ" }
    AREA { NAME="SISCD205_6_SEQ" }
    AREA { NAME="F-201_MOD" }
    AREA { NAME="COKE_CUTTING" }
    AREA { NAME="CRANE" }
    AREA { NAME="FRACT_TWR" }
    AREA { NAME="CD201_2_SEQ" }
    AREA { NAME="ANTI_FOAM" }
    AREA { NAME="MRX_COS" }
    AREA { NAME="FIRE_GAS" }
    AREA { NAME="ABS_STPR" }
    AREA { NAME="BD_SYS" }
    AREA { NAME="C3C4_SPLIT" }
    AREA { NAME="CD203_4_SEQ" }
    AREA { NAME="CD205_6_SEQ" }
    AREA { NAME="DEBUT" }
    AREA { NAME="DRUM_SEQ_OVW" }
    AREA { NAME="F-202_MOD" }
    AREA { NAME="F-203_MOD" }
    AREA { NAME="FEED" }
    AREA { NAME="NAPH_PRETREATER" }
    AREA { NAME="S_E_SYS" }
    AREA { NAME="T-403_AMINE" }
    AREA { NAME="P203_204" }
  }
  REMOTE_OPERATION_NETWORK_SUBSYSTEM
  {
    ENABLED=F
    COMMUNICATION_TYPE=SIMPLEX
    TIMEOUT_INTERVAL=400
    NETWORK_TYPE=REMOTE_NETWORK
    ENCRYPTION=F
    NTP_SERVER="0.0.0.0"
    NTP_BACKUP="0.0.0.0"
  }
  TERMINAL_SERVER_SUBSYSTEM
  {
    ENABLED=T
  }
  VIRTUAL_SIS_NETWORK
  {
  }
  ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="ADVISE_ALM"
  {
    VALUE
    {
      PRIORITY_NAME="LOG"
      ENAB=T
      INV=F
      ATYP="Change From Normal"
      MONATTR=""
      ALMATTR="ADVISE_ALM"
      LIMATTR=""
      PARAM1=""
      PARAM2=""
      SUPPTIMEOUT=1438560
      MASK=65535
      ISDEFAULTMASK=T
      ALARM_FUNCTIONAL_CLASSIFICATION=0
    }
    EXPLICIT_OVERRIDE=T
    VALUE_CHANGED=T
    HAS_DEFAULT_VALUE=F
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am open to trying and learning anything. I was wondering if I need to use "vector" but am still reading about how to use it correctly.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? Single-step through the code and find out why it exits early.

Comment: You don't need to write your C++ code for that. You need to get some `grep` or `awk`  working on your OS.

Comment: It does not exit early, it runs through the whole large text file and counts the exact number of lines it just finds 0 results.

Comment: 1) Run this in cmd prompt: `find "PRIORITY_NAME" fhx.txt>alarmlist.txt`. This should do the job and tell us whether the problem is with the system or with your program.
2) Please specify your compiler and its options set. Large files are handled differently with different compiler settings.

Answer (score 4):

Allocating memory to read in the whole file just to find strings inside sounds like a very bad idea, and unnecessary. I'm pretty sure you also should be using neiter `ios::ate` (starting at end of file instead of at beginning) nor `binary` (it's a text file...).

I think this is a case of "you don't have to write this, it has already been done"; just use a tool like `grep`, which should be available for virtually any operating system:

```
grep "PRIORITY_NAME" fhx.txt > alarmlist.txt
```

will do exactly what your program should do, would possibly be faster, and well-debugged.

Comment: While I agree that he shouldn't 'reinvent the wheel', this isn't actually an answer to his question. Recommending software to replace the code he is trying to write isn't why SO exists...

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about grep, I am reading about it now.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this correctly: Grep is a separate program that must be installed on the system then called via command line? If this is the case I can not use it. I am running this on a locked down system that nothing can be installed to. I have permission to run a console app but am unable to install anything. I guess I could try running grep through the flash drive.

Comment: Although this is a valid answer, I find the answer unconvincing since the answer does not help solve the root cause of the problem

Comment: @Cavell219 If you are on a Unix-based system (Mac OSX/Linux) `grep` doesn't need to be installed. `grep` is a program that is packaged with the OS, so you should be able to run it directly from the terminal with the command in this answer. Make sure that you are in the directory where the file (that you are searching) is located, or give an absolute path.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Unfortunately it is not a Unix based systems alas DOS based Windows. Windows server 2012.

Comment: @Cavell219 It looks like there's a Windows equivalent called [findstr](http://superuser.com/a/300820/333872). That should also be included int he OS - nothing to install.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice I think that my hint with ios::ate actually solves his problem, so I actually hope this solves his problem.

Comment: @Cavell219 If you can't just copy over a grep executable, you can't also just run your code, so I don't see your point about the system being locked down.

Comment: Some of the restrictions you mention here @Cavell219 may well be valuable information to insert into your question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The ios::ate is there to make sure the file size is the same, I have though commented it out and tried to rerun with the same results as before. Also they will allow me to run/install my code after it is reviewed. I am not allowed to install any outside software.

Comment: @Cavell219 So they'll let you install your own code but not trusted open-source executables? Interesting workplace.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Yes, I could give them the source of the open source executable and try that I guess. I will continue to work on my program and I guess if I can not solve my issue I will inquire about using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // reads the file and searches while there is still a line
    while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            ++counter;
            cout << counter << "\n"; //print out lines scanned for debug purposes

        // searches the file for PRIORITY_NAME
            if (line.find("PRIORITY_NAME") != string::npos)
            {
                alarmList << line << "\n"; // [rint results to seperate text file
                //getline(myfile, line);
                cout << line << "\n";// print to console for debug
            }
            line.clear();
        }
```

If in the above code, if all you want to do is find "PRIORITY_NAME" on a line by line basis, then you can clear the stream after you are done with each line.
Just before the next iteration of the while loop, maybe a clear would help.

```
 line.clear()
```

Comment: A good idea, and I tried it. But still had the same results :( Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Then the problem cannot be in the while loop.Since you clear the vector, it should not be  problem here if you are clearing it at the end of each iteration.

Comment: ' ifstream file("fhx.txt", ios::binary | ios::ate);
        cout << "The current open file size is " << file.tellg() << " bytes \n";

Comment: Does the above code print the correct size for a 1gb or so file after reading it??

Comment: Yes it shows the correct file size. Also counts the correct number of lines. This is why I am so confused...

Comment: The condition looks weird to me...  'while (getline(myfile, line))'

Comment: Can you try once by changing the condition in the while loop to be number of lines reached...Something like while(countoflines!=maxlines)

Comment: The condition is correct; that's how iostreams works.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/ ...Does this guy return null when eof is reached??

Comment: @Sebastian: Thanks for the clarification...The above link does not mention it clearly.It talks about some bit being set

Comment: @basav It does not return null. I can literally print out line and reprint the whole document to alarmList.txt